# Laravel sort and save position in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table in my database called 'users', it has these columns:
`id`, `points`, `rank`.

Everytime I update points, I want to sort all users by points desc and save rank position in that column.

I was wondering about getting all rows from database, sort them by using collection method and using update to update rank column. But i was wondering about how intense it would be to update 100k users one by one.

Maybe some experienced Laravel developers can suggest me a best possible solution in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want data orderred by `points` you can use

```
$user = User::orderBy('point', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: This just gets users. What I want to do is sort them by points and update their rank column respectively. For example user with most points will have rank 1, second with most points rank 2 and etc. I know that I can use update() function and pass ID of user and its rank, but it would be very inefficient if there are a lot of users. I was wondering maybe there is a better way to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

Alright the things you need here is an [Eloquent Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers) so each time you update the points on `update` it will sort all the users by points desc and save the rank position.

However with that amout of data I would never use collections or anything simillar as it will be slow, I suggest you using raw methods to do that.

Now there are two possible options if latency matters on this case then you can place all the logic in the observer itself like below:

First of seperate the observer logic to a different class like:

```
namespace App\Observers;

class UserRankObserver
{
    public function updated($model)
    {
       //check if points column its updated 
       //if yes then run the query to sort all user by points and save rank 
    }
}
```

Then on your `User` model you need to register the observer like :

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    User::observe(new \App\Observers\UserRankObserver);
}
```

Case two when the latency does not matter then I suggest on the method `updated` I would just pass the data to a background job to complete the action like :
    namespace App\Observers;

```
class UserRankObserver
{
    public function updated($model)
    {
       //check if points column its updated 
       //if yes then pass the data to a background job to complete the task.
       (new UpdateUserRankJob($data))->dispatch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Im using Event -> Listener for this task right know. I'm asking more about actual updating action. How to make such update as efficient as possible. Cause now updating each user one by one means 100k seperate mysql queries. It is really RAM consuming task in my opinion. Thats why im looking for a better way, but do not know any.

Comment: execute "SET @ pos:=1;"
update " UPDATE users SET rank=( SELECT @ pos:=@ pos + 1 ) ORDER BY posts DESC;"
I found this sql query that should do the trick. But when I try to run this query I get:

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SET @ pos := 1;" update " UPDATE users SET rank = ( SELECT @ pos := @ pos + 1 ) OR' at line 1 (SQL: execute "SET @ pos := 1;" update " UPDATE users SET rank = ( SELECT @ pos := @ pos + 1 ) ORDER BY points DESC;")

I use this line: DB::statement('execute "SET @ pos := 1;" update " UPDATE users SET rank = ( SELECT @ pos := @ pos + 1 ) ORDER BY points DESC;"');

what is wrong here?

Comment: How do you run the query?